# Using basic oauth to send a tweet

Tags: twitter, oauth

I was using basic auth to send tweets from a server every time a song changed. Now they have blocked basic auth and I am not sure how to incorporate it. I have a server at home that updates an html file on the webserver and then calls the following script to tweet out from that file. Any ideas on how to accomplish this simply?

```
  <?php


//====================================================
//         CONFIGURATION
//====================================================

// YOUR TWITTER USERNAME AND PASSWORD
$username = '#####';
$password = '#####';


DEFINE(htmlfile, '/homec/public_html/site.com/twitter.html');

$stationURL = "http://www.site.com";

$maxLimit = "139";

$da="";
$f=@fopen(htmlfile, "r");

if ($f!=0)
{
  $da=@fread($f, 4096);
  fclose($f);
}
else
{
  exit;
}

$da=str_replace("\r", "\n", $da);
$da=str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $da);
$d=explode("\n", $da);

$d[0]=trim($d[0], "|"); // title
$d[1]=trim($d[1], "|"); // artist

//====================================================
if ($d[0]=="" || $d[1]=="")
{
  // IF WE COULD NOT GRAB THE ARTIST AND
  // SONG TITLE FROM THE SAM-GENERATED HTML FILE,
  // WE'LL BAIL OUT NOW WITHOUT SUBMITTING ANY TEXT
  // TO TWITTER.
  exit;
}
else
{
  // SUCCESS IN GETTING ARTIST AND TITLE!
  // WE'LL PROCEED WITH BUILDING A TEXT STRING TO SUBMIT TO TWITTER.

  $message = urlencode('' . $d[1] . ' - ' . $d[0] . ' #bandradio #nowplaying ');

  $stationURL = urlencode(' ' . $stationURL);

  if ((strlen($message) + strlen($stationURL)) > $maxLimit)
  {
    // We have to truncate the artist-title string to make room for the station URL string.
    $message = substr($message, 0, (($maxLimit - 2) - strlen($stationURL)));
    $message .= ".." . $stationURL;
  }
  else
  {
    // No need to truncate, it all fits.
    $message =  $message . $stationURL;
  }
}  // if ($d[0]=="" || $d[1]=="")

//====================================================
// The twitter API address
$url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json';

// Set up and execute the curl process
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=$message");
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$resultArray = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: if format_your_code:
readibility++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest version of TwitterOAuth from http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/downloads Unpack the download and place the twitteroauth.php and OAuth.php files in the same directory as a file with the following code. Register an application at http://dev.twitter.com/apps and from your new apps details page click on "my access token" to get your access token. Fill the four required variables into the script below and you can then run it to post new tweets.

```
<?php
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
$connection = new TwitterOAuth('app consumer key', 'app consumer secret', 'my access token', 'my access token secret');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'text to be tweeted'));
```