# Trouble using PHP Twitter libraries to send tweet

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

To preface, I don't know much about PHP. However, I'm not sure that this is a PHP issue but maybe more of an issue with me understanding the libraries for connecting to Twitter.

I followed the tutorial here http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/hello-twitter-oauth-php/ which uses Matt Harris' twitter library. I didn't change anything except the keys which I obtained from twitter.

When I run the following code I get an unauthorized error code 401:

```
  $tweet_text = 'Hello Twitter';
  print "Posting...\n";
  $result = post_tweet($tweet_text);
  print "Response code: " . $result . "\n";

 function post_tweet($tweet_text) {

 require_once('tmhoauth/tmhOAuth.php');

 $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
'consumer_key' => '******',
'consumer_secret' => '******',
'user_token' => '******',
'user_secret' => '******',
)); 

// Make the API call
$connection->request('POST', 
$connection->url('1/statuses/update'), 
array('status' => $tweet_text));

return $connection->response['code'];
 }
?>
```

As I said previously, I am using the keys provided by twitter.

Could someong help me with trying to use the above library to test the twitter credientail validator at https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?

I also tried using the following example with the TwitterOAuth library from this SO post [Using basic oauth to send a tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633305/using-basic-oauth-to-send-a-tweet):

```
<?php
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
$connection = new TwitterOAuth('app consumer key', 'app consumer secret', 'my access     token', 'my access token secret');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'text to be tweeted'));
```

It didn't work as well; but it did forward the page to the author's github page!?!?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure the keys are correct I would advise you check the application settings within twitter to ensure that write mode is enabled.

Under the applications settings make sure the application type access is set to

> Read, Write and Access direct messages

*(Or at least Read/Write)*

Then perhaps try generating the access token again?

Comment: It actually was the access token not having the proper permissions. I had to remove the access rights for the app, then recreate the access key. Apparently if you ask for the access tokens before you set the application setting to Read, Write, and Access, the token will get the same access as the application at creation time. It will not change as you change the permission level of the app.  Thanks!

Comment: Twitter should tell it, if you change the permissions, you have to generate the keys again... what ever, thank you for advice